# what's mean of "get your backs"?

Tags: phrases

there, I got a sentence from television "Lost": "`Besides, I'm gonna be in there to get your backs.`". I am little confused with this words: `get your backs`. Can anyone give me some clue about it?

Comment: It's derived from the longer phrase "I've got your back covered," meaning that I am providing defensive cover to ensure that no one sneaks up behind you undetected and stabs, shoots, or otherwise attacks you in the back.

Answer (score 1):

*[get your back](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%27ve%20got%20your%20back)*: you are going to watch out and be a second set of eyes for someone. You will look out for their best interests and let them know if they have missed something.